# Multiple delete statements with single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Given two tables, `photos` and `keywords`, where `photos.ID = keywords.photos`, how can I delete the same rows from both tables in a single query?  The `photos` table has a single record, while `keywords` has 9 references to the `photos` record.

I've tried

```
DELETE FROM photos 
INNER JOIN keywords ON photos.ID = keywords.photo 
WHERE photos.ID = 262;
```

I get a Error 1064 stating an error exists starting at `INNER JOIN keywords` and continuing for the rest of the statement.

However, when I conovert the `DELETE` statement to a `SELECT *` via

```
SELECT * FROM photos
INNER JOIN keywords ON photos.ID = keywords.photo
WHERE photos.ID = 262;
```

, I get a set of 9 rows returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the name of the table where you want to delete

```
DELETE photos 
FROM photos 
     INNER JOIN keywords ON photos.ID = keywords.photo 
WHERE photos.ID = 262;
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Why does the table qualifier need to be included in this statement, but not from normal `DELETE` usage?

Comment: because it involves multiple tables that's why you need to specify where the deletion of records should takes place. `:D`

Answer (score 1):

You can't explicitly delete from more than one table.

However, if keywords.photos is foreign keyed to photos.id with "on delete cascade", they will get deleted when you delete from photos

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use the MyISAM engine for this table, which means no foreign key support.  Thus the necessity of implementing the same logic in my code.