# Delete Multiple rows in several tables

Tags: c#, html, sql, database

I have 3 tables in an SQL database:

1. Animal Status
2. Animals
3. Cart

I want to be able to delete several items from the *Animals* and *Animal Status* tables based on the cart.

What's the same between all the tables is the AnimalID which is the primary key in all the tables and based on that I'm supposed to delete them. But at the same time I need to delete it for someone with a specific email.

Example is if I have someone with the email 123@gmail.com and this person has 2 animals in his cart 1 with the ID 123 and the other with the id 456
I need to delete these 2 specific animals from the other 2 tables.

I know how to do it for 1 table but not when I have several tables that depend on each other along with them depending on the specific email when there are also other emails and animals in the cart.

Here is how it works on the outside:

```
x= AnimalStatus.Delete(AdoptCart.GetAnimalId(Session["email"].ToString()).ToString());
            if (x > 0)
            {
                x = Animal.Delete(AdoptCart.GetAnimalId(Session["email"].ToString()).ToString());
                if (x > 0)
                {
                    AdoptCart.RemoveAllbyEmail(Session["email"].ToString());
```

Here are all the deletion codes in the order they work:

Removes the AnimalStatus based on the animals ID:

```
static public int Delete(string id)
    {
        int rowsAffected;
        string strSql = string.Format("delete from AnimalStatus where AnimalID='" + id + "'");
        rowsAffected = (int)dataservice.ExecuteNonQuery(strSql);
        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

Removes an animal from the animal table based on the animal's ID:

```
 static public int Delete(string id)
        {
            int rowsAffected;
            string strSql = string.Format("delete from Animal where AnimalID='" + id + "'");
            rowsAffected = (int)dataservice.ExecuteNonQuery(strSql);
            return rowsAffected;
        }
```

Removes all animals from the Cart Table:

```
static public int Remove(string AnimalID) 
    {
        int rowsAffected;
        string strSql = string.Format("delete from Cart where AnimalID='" + AnimalID + "'");
        rowsAffected = (int)dataservice.ExecuteNonQuery(strSql);
        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

**Issue with this code is that all of that only deletes 1 animal and I need several removed.**

I have tried creating a statement like this, but I didn't manage to make it work.:

```
Delete Animal.*, AnimalStatus.*

FROM     Animal INNER JOIN
                  AnimalStatus ON Animal.AnimalID = AnimalStatus.AnimalID INNER JOIN
                  Cart ON Animal.AnimalID = Cart.AnimalID
WHERE  (Cart.UserEmail = N'Email')
```

Based on the example I gave in words the ones that are supposed to be deleted are the following marked in `//removed`.

```
Cart Table
 | AnimalID | Email_Addr |
--------------------------------------
| 123 | 123@gmail.com | //removed
| 456 | 123@gmail.com | //removed
| 765 | jj@gmail.com  |
| 343 | bb@gmail.com  |
| 256 | cc@gmail.com  |

Animal Status Table
 | AnimalID | Vaccinated |
--------------------------------------
| 123 | Yes | //removed
| 456 | Yes | //removed
| 765 | No  |
| 343 | No  |
| 256 | No  |

Animals Tables
 | AnimalID | Age |
--------------------------------------
| 123 | 3 | //removed
| 456 | 4 | //removed
| 765 | 3 |
| 343 | 7 |
| 256 | 10|
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Please show what you tried, so that we can comment or improve on it. Also note that Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Finally, which DBMS: Oracle? Sql Server? MySql? etc etc

Comment: Sample data as in showing you pictures of the tables?

Comment: Did you take into account referential integrity (aka "foreign keys" with cascading delete)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167696/multiple-delete-statements-with-single-query

Comment: @Cheyenne, sample data would be structure of all involved tables, and the query you are using to delete rows from one of the tables.

Comment: Please show us the structure of the tables. Use `CREATE TABLE` statements for this **NOT** images. Please also also provide sample data for the tables (as `INSERT INTO` statements, again **NOT** images) and the desired for this sample data (as text and, you guessed it, **NOT** images).

Comment: @Cheyenne, also take a look at [Foreign Keys](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) as mentioned by _Psi_. Usually you want to structure tables in a way that any _Animals_ row that gets deleted also causes any "references" to be removed.

Comment: I edited the post to hopefully make it better to understand. I didn't really understand the foreign key structure in the example in the link provided will the child column in my case would be AnimalD?

Comment: You can use a Cascade.
In engines like mysql, for example, when you add a Foreing Key, you can determine the delete action to "cascade", so, if a record in this table was deleted, it automaticly "cascade" the delete to the record on the other table mentioned in the foreign key. Doing this, you will need to delete the record just in on table and the engine will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your current work there are a few things you could do. You could rewrite your query logic like you're asking, but what I'm not seeing in your example is primary/foreign key relationships. So cascade won't work with how you currently have your tables set up. This is a good write up of cascade delete. [Cascade Delete](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

So if you don't want to rewrite everything you really could just do all of this in your C# code. All you'd have to do is loop through the cart table and get all of the id's that have the e-mail "123@gmail.com" and call your three delete statements. You'd just need to write a method to grab the id's and call the delete methods until the id variable is empty.

It just depends where you want all of the logic to exist, in sql or in your C# code. If you're using Entity Framework, whether code first or database first, you have options to use LINQ Query syntax or extension methods. Just depends on preference really.